# How to implement RSA-OAEP algorithm with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, rsa

Is there any way to implement the RSA-OAEP algorithm with xslt??

I mean... if I have this:

```
<Payment>
   <CardholderName>Foo Bar</CardholderName>
   <CardNumber>1111 2222 3333 4444</CardNumber>
   <Serial>123</SerialCode>
</Payment>
```

transform into this other:

```
<Payment>
   <CardholderName>Foo Bar</CardholderName>
   <CardNumber>1111 22</CardNumber>
   <Serial>123</SerialCode>
   <TokenizedCardNumber>{CardNumber tokenized with RSA-OAEP}</TokenizedCardNumber>
</Payment>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The theoretical answer is yes, for XSLT is Turing complete. The practical answer is you want to find an XSLT parser/engine that lets you call into other code that can do the RSA-OAEP thing for you. Definitely possible with Java (e.g.: Xalan) and PHP (its XSLT extension/bindings to libxslt).

Comment: I guess it is possible, but tremendously complicated and probably quite slow, especially with XSLT-1.0. Your first step would be to locate/create a functional representation of the RSA algorithm. The second step would be to implement it taking extreme care of all side-cases and number representation limitations. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user268396 XSLT is Turing complete - but Turing completeness does include the generation of random numbers.

Comment: @michael.hor257k where there is a will there is `<xsl:param>`. Most engines let you set those so you can cheat a bit. Of course none of this is a *good* idea. ;)

Comment: Hi @user268396 I am using the OS libraries (to test the xslt files I use the command `xsltproc`). I am pretty newbie with xslt and I thought that it wasn´t related to the programming language (I am using golang to the "normal" code).

Comment: Hi @zx485 The cost in the process time is not relevant... the xml produced is used to request a server that takes over 10-15 seconds to respond. So, even the xslt use 1 second, it is not relevant. I didn´t try anything, because I want to know if it is possible to do and if exists a common solution.